# ServiceStack: Is this correct way to register generic type for MonoTouch?

Tags: servicestack

I have a service request, for example:

```
public class UpdateUserActions
{
    public Dictionary<string, int> Actions { get; set; }
}
```

I registered it in Aot.Init method, just like the way in ServiceStack.Text.Tests.MonoTouch:

```
public static void Init()
{
    JsConfig.RegisterForAot ();
    JsConfig.RegisterTypeForAot<UpdateUserActions>();
    JsConfig.RegisterTypeForAot<Dictionary<string, int>>();
}
```

And called Aot.Init in AppDelegate. But it does't seems to fix the JIT compiler error. Still got below error:

> DEBUG: Exception Reading Response Error: Attempting to JIT compile
>   method 'ServiceStack.Text.Common.ToStringDictionaryMethods`3:WriteIDictionary
>   (System.IO.TextWriter,object,ServiceStack.Text.Common.WriteObjectDelegate,ServiceStack.Text.Common.WriteObjectDelegate)'
>   while running with --aot-only.